# Dynamic changes to thread stack size in Solaris 9?

Tags: multithreading, stack, size, solaris, hp-ux

I am looking for a configurable / tunable on Solaris 9 through which I can change the default thread stack size *without* recompiling the code to use "pthread_attr_setstacksize"

For example on HPUX 11.11 / 11.23 the environment variable "PTHREAD_DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE" can be exported (available via HPUX patches PHCO_38307 / PHCO_38955 ) - Is there a  equivalent Solaris 9 way to achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Use Kernel Parameters

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/817-1759/6mhfh76gs/index.html